# woocommerce get chosen shipping method - error Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

In my child theme's functions.php I have this function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_cash_on_delivery' );

function payment_gateway_cash_on_delivery( $available_gateways ) {

  $selected_shipping_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
  
  if ( in_array($selected_shipping_id, ['flexible_shipping_5_5', 'flexible_shipping_7_6' ]) && isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] )) {
    unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
  }

  return $available_gateways;

}
```

WP sends me these warnig about an error at the first row of the function

> Podrobnosti chyby
> =================
> Na řádku č. 61 v souboru /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/functions.php došlo k chybě typu E_ERROR. Chybová zpráva: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/functions.php:61
> Stack trace:
> #0 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): payment_gateway_cash_on_delivery()
> #1 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-includes/plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #2 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php(160): apply_filters()
> #3 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-admin/src/Features/OnboardingTasks.php(91): WC_Payment_Gateways->get_available_payment_gateways()
> #4 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-admin/src/Features/OnboardingTasks.php(148): Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Features\OnboardingTasks::get_settings()
> #5 /hosting/www/weftsandwarps.com/Zlaterouno/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): Automattic\WooComm

My guess is the function is called when no method has been chosen?

Answer (score 0):

There is not always an initiated WooCommerce session when calling this function, e.g. in the admin area.

You can check first if there is a session, or I would suggest to add this at the beginning of your function, so it's only triggered for customers:

`if ( ! is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) return $available_gateways;`